# Android make two overlapping views receive and handle the same touch event

Tags: android, touch, view, overlapping, touch-event

I'm using a `RelativeLayout` to overlap two different views. Both Views fill the entire Screen. 
If the user touches the screen, I want both views to receive the `TouchEvent` and to excecute their own `onTouch`-Methods. At the moment, only one view receives the `TouchEvent`
How can I make both views receive the TouchEvent?

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: Here's the code

```
touchView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                view1.onTouchEvent(event);
                view2.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a third invisible View and place it on top of the overlapping part. Then in its TouchEvent perform the actions of those two TouchEvents

Comment: thank you for the quick answer! Your Method is actually working for me. I'm going to post the code if someone is having the same Problem.

Answer (score 0):

For top view assign clickable=false

it will allow the touch to intercept through it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get to check if the rawX & rawY of the `TouchEvent` are within the hitRect of the view that didn't get the event. If it did, you can use `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` to send the `TouchEvent` tot the view that didn't get the event